# background-color not working for z-indexed elements

Tags: html, css

i'm stumped. i'm creating a tabular navigation setup from scratch because the jquery tabbed pane destroys iframes in firefox. so i'm using z-index to stack the elements instead of show-hide. that's how i got started down this road. the only elements in my html that will NOT take a background color are the ones that take a z-index value. As you will see if you run this, they need a background color.

here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "center_console">
            <div id = "portal_wrapper">
                <div id="navtabs_bar">
                    <span id = "connect" class = "navtab">Connect</span>
                    <span id = "create" class = "navtab">Create</span>
                    <span id = "discover" class = "navtab">Discover</span>
                    <span id = "progress" class = "navtab">Progress</span>
                </div>
                <div id = "portal_display">
                    <div id = "connect_display" class = "portal_display_big4">
                        <!-- <iframe id = "video_embedded" width="680" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xnMJWq1BVuI?modestbranding=1&controls=1&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" autoplay allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                    </div>
                    <div id = "create_display" class = "portal_display_big4">create display
                    </div>
                    <div id = "discover_display" class = "portal_display_big4">discover display
                    </div>
                    <div id = "progress_display" class = "portal_display_big4">progress display
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/interface.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
#portal_wrapper{
    width:680px;
    height:360px;
}
#portal_display{
    position:relative;
}
.portal_display_big4{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
}

#navtabs_bar{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}


.navtab{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid green;
}

#connect_display{
    background-color:red;
}
#create_display{
    background-color:green;
}
#connect_display{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

and interface.js:

```
$('.navtab').on('click', function(){
    //alert('ok');
    id = this.id;
    display_id = '#' + id + '_display';
    $('#connect_display').css('z-index', '0');
    $('#create_display').css('z-index', '0');
    $('#discover_display').css('z-index', '0');
    $('#progress_display').css('z-index', '0');
    $(display_id).css('z-index', '1');
    //$(display_id).css('color', 'red');
    //alert($(display_id).css('background'));
});
```

I've tried:

changing the position from relative to absolute...
checking the console in firefox and chrome... nothing
removing background color from every other element... nothing
checked all links to the css blah blah blah. there is something i'm missing here

any ideas?

edit... ok so i decided to try putting a div inside the displayed element and giving THAT a background color. essentially treating the absolutely positioned and z-indexed element as a wrapper. here is what i ended up with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "center_console">
            <div id = "portal_wrapper">
                <div id="navtabs_bar">
                    <span id = "connect" class = "navtab">Connect</span>
                    <span id = "create" class = "navtab">Create</span>
                    <span id = "discover" class = "navtab">Discover</span>
                    <span id = "progress" class = "navtab">Progress</span>
                </div>
                <div id = "portal_display">
                    <div id = "connect_display" class = "portal_display_big4">
                        <iframe id = "video_embedded" width="680" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xnMJWq1BVuI?modestbranding=1&controls=1&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" autoplay allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "create_display" class = "portal_display_big4">
                        <div class = "inner_wrapper" >create display</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "discover_display" class = "portal_display_big4">
                        <div class = "inner_wrapper" >discover display</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "progress_display" class = "portal_display_big4">
                        <div class = "inner_wrapper" >progress display</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/interface.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the updated css

```
*{
    font-family:Avenir;
}

#portal_wrapper{
    width:680px;
    height:360px;
}
#portal_display{
    position:relative;
}
.portal_display_big4{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
}

#navtabs_bar{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}


.navtab{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.inner_wrapper{
    background-color:blue;
    height:360px;
}
```

So this works, and basically solves my problem... but i'd like to know why i wasn't able to give a background color to the z-indexed element. What gives? I can't find a reason.

Comment: Too vague... what is it that you want to achieve? A background color for the tabs?

Comment: they need a background color, otherwise all the words appear jumbled. but i just found a fix i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your portal display has no height because all the elements inside it are positioned absolutely therefore when you add height 100% to your inner elements they are in effect set to `height:0px`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put height: 100%; in the relative div with the id portal_display

```
#portal_display{
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See your working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y3cb/)

Also if changed your js a little bit. No need to work with z-indexes ;)
[fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y3cb/1/)

```
$('.navtab').on('click', function(){
    id = this.id;
    display_id = '#' + id + '_display';
    $('.portal_display_big4').hide();
    $(display_id).show();
});
```

Comment: thank you richard that would work except i can't use show/hide because it resets the iframe youtube player and i can't have that. thanks for pointing out that i can use the class selector though!

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs some height. They have 0 height.